# How to set regex for this text?

Tags: regex, text

I want to get words array from text like this:

> #yān,yè,yīn#

I make the pattern `#((.*?),{0,1})+#` to get the array `yān`,`yè` and `yīn`（the word in the array is special not in English format）, however it doesn't work as I thought.
What should I do to solve this,can anyone help me?

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe,

```
 (?<=#|,)[^,#]+
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/tLecC8/1/)

or,

```
[^,#]+(?=,|#)
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/LpPO6i/1/)

would extract those desired strings.

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/LpPO6i/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/LpPO6i/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

Answer (score 0):

If the `\G` anchor and a positive lookbehind is supported and you want to match that data structure where the `#` is present at the start and the end you might use a capturing group.

```
(?:#|\G(?!^))([^#,\r\n]+),?(?=[^\r\n#]*#(?<!,#))
```

In parts

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `#` Match literally
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert position at the end of previous match, not at the start
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `([^#,\r\n]+)` Capture **group 1**, match any char except `#`, `,` or a newline
- `,?` Match optional `,`
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is

  - `[^\r\n#]*` Match 0+ times any char except `#` or a newline
  - `#(?<!,#)` Match `#` and assert what is directly on the left is not a `,`
- `)` Close positive lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vhfACO/1)